# IllegalAccessError when instantiating HttpSolrServer

Tags: java, maven, solr, solrj

I am executing a SolrQuery on my class under a Maven project. When trying to execute the query I am getting this error:

```
SEVERE: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access field org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.SINGLETON from class org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.staticInitialize(LoggerFactory.java:83)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.<clinit>(LoggerFactory.java:73)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.<clinit>(HttpSolrServer.java:91)
....
```

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
  <artifactId>solr-core</artifactId>
  <version>4.8.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
  <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
  <version>4.8.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.12</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.12</version>
</dependency>
```

It's working in another project which is not using Maven but by adding jars. I used in Maven the same versions used in the normal web project.
Can anyone help with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the slf4j dependencies. SolrJ is pulling in different versions of those dependencies. It appears that the versions you are pulling in are overriding the older version that SorlJ uses. This should be what is causing your error.

Comment: I deleted the slf4j dependencies but I keep getting the same exception. I will try to delete all dependencies and go for it step by step. Thanks anyway

Comment: Nope it's not working neither. I deleted all other dependencies that thier versions are  pulled by SolrJ.